# ¿Complemento de botones Laravel DataTables?

Tags: laravel, datatables

Estoy  implementado datatables  del lado del servidor, donde muestro un listado de todos los usuarios registrados del sistema, estoy tratando de utilizar el complemento de botones (excel, pdf, print), **Existe alguna manera de indicarle al datatables que columnas imprimir y cuales no imprimir?** la cuestion es que tengo una columna llamada acciones (que son los botones editar y eliminar) y esa es la columna que pretendo no imprimir. Hay alguna manera de lograr esto?

Controlador UserController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use DataTables;
use App\Providers\UserWasCreated;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests\SaveUserRequest;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()    
    {
        return view('admin.users.index');
    }

  public function dataTable()
    {
        $usuarios = User::query()
        ->allowed()
        ->get();;

        return dataTables::of($usuarios)
            ->addColumn('created_at', function ($usuarios){
                return $usuarios->created_at->format('d-m-y');
            })   
            ->addColumn('rol', function ($usuarios){
                return $usuarios->roles->implode('name', ', ');
            })   

            ->addColumn('accion', function ($usuarios) {
                return view('admin.users.partials._action', [
                    'usuarios' => $usuarios,
                    'url_show' => route('admin.users.show', $usuarios->id),                        
                    'url_edit' => route('admin.users.edit', $usuarios->id),                              
                    'url_destroy' => route('admin.users.destroy', $usuarios->id)
                ]);
            })
            ->parameters([
                    'dom'          => 'Bfrtip',
                    'buttons'      => ['csv', 'excel', 'print'],
            ])
            ->addIndexColumn()   
            ->rawColumns(['rol', 'created_at', 'accion'])                
            ->make(true);  
    }
```

esta es mi vista user.index.blade

```
<?php
use App\User;
?>

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('header')    
    <h1>
        USUARIOS
        <small>Listado</small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="active">Usuarios</li>
    </ol> 
@stop

@section('content')
    <div class="panel panel-primary">        
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Listado de usuarios     
            @can('create', $user = new User())
                <a href="{{ route('admin.users.create') }}"  id="btn-btn-create" class="btn btn-success pull-right modal-show" style="margin-top: -8px;" title="Crear Usuario"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Crear usuario</a>
            @endcan
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="datatable" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>                        
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Rol</th>  
                        <th>Agregado</th>                                
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>                
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> 
@stop

@include('admin.users.partials._modal')

@push('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">    
@endpush

@push('scripts')   
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/adminlte/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="{{ asset('js/user.js') }}"></script>

    <script>
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['csv', 'excel', 'print'],
            ajax: "{{ route('users.table') }}",            
            columns: [                
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'email', name: 'email'},   
                {data: 'rol', name: 'rol'},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'agregado'},                  
                {data: 'accion', name: 'accion'}                          
            ]
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Por favor me podrían ayudar a resolver este inconveniente?.

Comment: Del lado cliente podes probar como en [este ejemplo](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html) para exportar a excel las columnas con indices 0, 1, 2 y 5 `dom: 'Bfrtip', buttons: [{ extend: 'excelHtml5', exportOptions: { columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 5]  } }, ]`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias me sirvio lo que me indicaste

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ me doy cuenta que agregando la modificacion que me indicaste pierdo esta propiedad:lengthMenu.

Comment: es raro ya que antes lo tenia por defecto ahora intente agregar lo siguiente pero no me funciona: ```lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],```

Comment: Tal vez tengas que configurar algo desde el backend, nunca usé datatables en BE, como lo estas haciendo. Ese es el ejemplo oficial de cómo exportar las columnas seleccionadas, que es solo frontend